# dropdown box height: browser/OS compatibility issues

Tags: html, css, cross-platform, cross-browser

Having a strange browser/OS compatibility issue with dropdowns.  Specifically, I'm trying to set the height of the select element to match the text input next to it.

- On PC, it renders fine in all browsers.
- On Mac, in Firefox the height works but the text in the select seems oversized (see the first image below).
- On Mac in Chrome, the height is not set properly at all (see second image below).

Here's the relevant CSS:

```
form select {
    float: left;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-top: 4px;
}
```

Any ideas why I'm experiencing this?  Is there a way to reset or standardize the styles of dropdowns across browsers and OS?

OSX, Firefox:

[image: osx ff]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyhMo.png

OSX, Chrome:

[image: osx chrome]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwbVX.png

Answer (score 1):

You should look into CSS Resets. I use them sparingly depending on the application but for situations like this, they certainly do come in handy.

Here's an example resetter:

```
html{
    color:#000;
    background:#FFF;
}
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, code, form, fieldset, legend, input, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
fieldset, img {
    border:0;
}
address, caption, cite, code, dfn, em, strong, th, var {
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
}
li {
    list-style:none;
}
caption, th {
    text-align:left;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-size:100%;
    font-weight:normal;
}
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
}
abbr, acronym {
    border:0;
    font-variant:normal;
}
sup {
    vertical-align:text-top;
}
sub {
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
}
input, textarea, select {
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
    font-weight:inherit;
}
input, textarea, select {
    *font-size:100%;
}
legend {
    color:#000;
}
```

A CSS Reset removes and neutralizes the inconsistent default styling of HTML elements, creating a level playing field across [A-grade browsers](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/articles/gbs/index.html#history) and providing a sound foundation upon which you can explicitly declare your intentions

Answer (score 1):

[Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/) is similar to AlienWebguy's answer, but uses a saner set of defaults. Their code for forms is:

```
/* =============================================================================
   Forms
   ========================================================================== */

/*
 * Corrects margin displayed oddly in IE6/7
 */

form {
    margin: 0;
}

/*
 * Define consistent margin and padding
 */

fieldset {
    margin: 0 2px;
    padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em;
}

/*
 * 1. Corrects color not being inherited in IE6/7/8/9
 * 2. Corrects alignment displayed oddly in IE6/7
 */

legend {
    border: 0; /* 1 */
    *margin-left: -7px; /* 2 */
}

/*
 * 1. Corrects font size not being inherited in all browsers
 * 2. Addresses margins set differently in IE6/7, F3/4, S5, Chrome
 * 3. Improves appearance and consistency in all browsers
 */

button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    margin: 0; /* 2 */
    vertical-align: baseline; /* 3 */
    *vertical-align: middle; /* 3 */
}

/*
 * 1. Addresses FF3/4 setting line-height using !important in the UA stylesheet
 * 2. Corrects inner spacing displayed oddly in IE6/7
 */

button,
input {
    line-height: normal; /* 1 */
    *overflow: visible;  /* 2 */
}

/*
 * Corrects overlap and whitespace issue for buttons and inputs in IE6/7
 * Known issue: reintroduces inner spacing
 */

table button,
table input {
    *overflow: auto;
}

/*
 * 1. Improves usability and consistency of cursor style between image-type 'input' and others
 * 2. Corrects inability to style clickable 'input' types in iOS
 */

button,
html input[type="button"], 
input[type="reset"], 
input[type="submit"] {
    cursor: pointer; /* 1 */
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 2 */
}

/*
 * Addresses box sizing set to content-box in IE8/9
 */

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*
 * 1. Addresses appearance set to searchfield in S5, Chrome
 * 2. Addresses box sizing set to border-box in S5, Chrome (include -moz to future-proof)
 */

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box; /* 2 */
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

/*
 * Corrects inner padding displayed oddly in S5, Chrome on OSX
 */

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*
 * Corrects inner padding and border displayed oddly in FF3/4
 * www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/05/14/the-devils-in-the-details-fixing-dojos-toolbar-buttons/
 */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*
 * 1. Removes default vertical scrollbar in IE6/7/8/9
 * 2. Improves readability and alignment in all browsers
 */

textarea {
    overflow: auto; /* 1 */
    vertical-align: top; /* 2 */
}
```

Comment: I think alienwebguy's is YUI's http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/yahoo-css-reset-yui-3/ I never liked yahoo until they discovered/invented JSONP and earned back their credibility. Can you explain the difference between yours and his?

Comment: All browsers ship with a set of default styles, which are all slightly different. A CSS Reset (such as YUI) combats these differences by resetting everything to "zero," leaving it up to you to rebuild all styles from scratch. The point of Normalize.css, OTOH, is to reset everything to a common baseline that makes sense, but is NOT "zero." E.g., CSS Reset says "strong {font-weight:normal}" and now your stylesheet must include "strong {font-weight:bold}" because 99.99% of the time, that is what you wanted anyway. Compare Normalize.css, which says "strong {font-weight:bold}" and you're done.